# Invalid Constraint when using the addConstraint with the xpress library in python

Tags: python, numpy, binary, solver, xpress-optimizer

When running this code

```
import numpy as np
import xpress as xp

z = np.array([xp.var () for i in range (200)]).reshape (4,5,10)
t = np.array([xp.var (vartype = xp.binary) for i in range (200)]).reshape (4,5,10)
p = xp.problem()
p.addVariable(z,t)
p.addConstraint(z <= 1 + t)
```

I get the following error

```
Invalid constraint
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModelError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
      3 p = xp.problem()
      4 p.addVariable(z,t)
----> 5 p.addConstraint(z <= 1 + t)
      6 p.addConstraint(xp.Sum(z[i][j][k] for i in range (4) for j in range (5)) <= 4 for k in range (10))
ModelError: Invalid constraint
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, since I'm not sure how to fix it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dtype` of the np arrays must be explicitly set to xp.npvar. This is stated [here](https://www.fico.com/fico-xpress-optimization/docs/latest/solver/optimizer/python/HTML/chNumpy_sec_secNumpy.html):

> The NumPy arrays must have the attribute dtype equal to xpress.npvar
> (abbreviated to xp.npvar here) in order to use the matricial/vectorial
> form of the comparison (<=, =, >=), arithmetic (+, -, *, /, **), and
> logic (&, |) operators.

If you don't set the type to npvar, the wrong overloads for these operators will be used and `z <= 1 - t` will just be an array of booleans.

This is the correct way to create your arrays:

```
z = np.array([xp.var () for i in range (200)], dtype=xp.npvar).reshape (4,5,10)
t = np.array([xp.var (vartype = xp.binary) for i in range (200)], dtype=xp.npvar).reshape (4,5,10)
```